# Check if characters are part of a String

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, linq

I want to check if a set of characters are part of String variable are not,
Ideally I would do one of the below,

1. Store the characters in a list and loop through each character to check if they exist in the string.
2. Form a simple if statement with OR operations in case the character set is small.

Is there a better way to do this, may be using LINQ.

As an example I want to check if any of the characters '>' or '<' or '=', are part of the string 'a > b and b != 10'.

Comment: `.IndexOf` method will do your work.

Comment: `.Contains` should also work.

Comment: Define your problem a little better. Do you need to know if *any* of `>`,`<` or `=` are in your string? Or *all* of them? Do you need to know *which* ones. What have you tried so far? What do you mean by efficient? Faster? Less memory intensive? Less lines of code? What profiling have you done to suggest what you currently have isn't efficient enough?

Comment: I want to check if any of the characters '>',  '<',  '=' is present in string variable. I'm looking for less of line of code, may be a single liner. I would have used a loop to check individual characters using IndexOf or Contains methods. Tim's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136.aspx) + [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697.aspx):

```
bool contains = stringVariable.Intersect("><=").Any();
```

Answer (score 2):

Should not be too difficult:

```
var content = "a<b";

var isContained = content.Any(c => c == '<')
```

..or for a list of characters:

```
var charList = new []{'<', '>'};
var isAnyContained = content.Any(c => charList.Contains(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `String.IndexOfAny` method:

```cs
string myString = "a > b and b != 10";
if (myString.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '<', '>', '=' }) >= 0)
    {
    // ...
    }
```

Or

```vb
Dim myString As String = "a > b and b != 10"
If myString.IndexOfAny({">"c, ">"c, "="c}) >= 0 Then
    ' ...
End If
```